# derivative of "length element"

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I am trying to understand the derivation of [this webpage](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Epeastman/statmech/phasespace.html) about Liouville’s Theorem.

Let us have a very small volume $V=\delta x\delta p$ in phase $(x,p)$ space. The total time derivative of $V$ becomes (Eq. $2$ of that page)
$$
\frac{dV}{dt} = \delta x \frac{d\delta p}{dt} + \delta p \frac{d\delta x}{dt} \\
= \delta x \left(\frac{d(p +\delta p)}{dt}-\frac{dp}{dt}\right) + \delta p \left(\frac{d(x +\delta x)}{dt}-\frac{dx}{dt}\right) \tag{2}
$$
Then they say that if we assume that $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dp}{dt}$ are linear in $x$ and $p$, respectively, then we can write
$$
\frac{d(x +\delta x)}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt} + \delta x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right) \tag{3}
$$

I want to know where does Eq. $3$ come from?

Comment: Maybe the chain rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple [Taylor series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series), which is
$$
f(x+\delta x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(\delta x)^n}{n!} \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}  = f(x) + \delta x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x) +\cdots
$$
So, till linear order, we have

$$
\frac{d(x +\delta x)}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} \left( x + \delta x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}x \right) \\
=\frac{dx}{dt} + \delta x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right) 
$$